# Custom Module Route run by External Cron Task

Tags: 8

I created a Drupal 8 module that cURL to a SFTP, grab a xml file and write it on the files folder. This module as a route (with _access: 'TRUE'), pointing to a controller that does the task.

While I'm connected as admin, and go to that route URL, the XML is downloaded as expected. When I do it as an anonymous user, it doesn't work, not throwing any error.
My goal is to have this route run by an external Cron task (every 5 minutes). However, when it runs, it's not recognized as admin, so it doesn't work.

What would be the best practice to have it working with a Cron Task but also secure enough so that not everybody could run it by going to that URL ?

Comment: I've never really had much luck with the whole `access => TRUE' (Drupal 7) or `_access: 'TRUE'`, but perhaps you need to specify `TRUE` without the quotes. Or use a `'access content'` for a permission that is usually granted to anonymous users. However seeing as you do not actually want a route, you may be interested in running via `hook_cron` or adding a Queue worker that is then run by an external queue processor like RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an API endpoint with authentication. Like:
mysite.com/api/crontasks?u=user&p=password

And then authenticate it via controller!

Comment: It is answer to the question: "what would be the best practise...". In my opinion that would be the best practise. I don't understand you.

Comment: It was actually helpful. The cron task now uses an authentication for a better practice. As for the admin access, I used the account_switcher service to be connected as admin while I'm doing my stuff and then switchBack when it's done.